# Testing Experience for SOA WebServices

Tags: unit-testing, tomcat, soa

Hello I want to test automatic my SOA WebService, I found soapUI and it looks also really nice.

But how I can start my SOA Service in an Tomcat (EmbeddedTomcat?) or AXIS Servlet Container?
Because we don't want to install on our Hutson Build Server an Tomcat Server.

So the question which are the ways to go when we will Test our SOA Service from outside in an automatic unit test environment?

Thanks for answers

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "SOA WebService"? SOAP/HTTP web service?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install a Tomcat server on your buildserver, you could have another server running tomcat, which you can remote deploy to from your build server on every successful build. Then run your soapUI tests against the remote server. There are both Ant and Maven plugins for Tomcat, which can do remote deployment. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing%20Manager%20Commands%20With%20Ant, http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/introduction.html